# Run Script + Desktop File as Root w/out Prompt

Tags: permissions, scripts, sudo, .desktop

I have two files, one being a desktop file, the other being a shell script. The desktop file is meant to open the shell script, and execute it in a xTerm GUI as root, **without needing "sudo password."**

I was told to remove `sudo` completely from the shell script, leaving [this](http://pastebin.com/HLj30UWz). Since the program needed root access, I edited my /etc/sudoers to the following:

```
david ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/home/david/upgrade.sh
david ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/home/david/Desktop/Upgrade.desktop
```

As I was instructed to, and from there, configured the desktop file. I started with the following:

```
xterm -e sudo sh -p /home/david/upgrade.sh
```

But when I ran the desktop file it still asked for my password. I thought that the `sudo` in the desktop file could be the problem, but upon removing it, the xTerm window no longer opens. How can I execute this shell script from the desktop file without entering my password?

Comment: Ok a couple of things...<br/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, remove your line about the desktop file from `/etc/sudoers`, it's not needed.

Second, you configured the exact command `/home/david/upgrade.sh` to run with `NOPASSWD`, not `sh -p /home/david/upgrade.sh` which you try to run in the `xterm` window. You must run the configured command to profit from the `NOPASSWD` setting:

```
xterm -e sudo /home/david/upgrade.sh
```

By the way, the shebang of your script file specifies `/bin/bash` as interpreter, but you attempted to run it with `/bin/sh`. The outcome is the same as long as you don't use Bash specific features, but you should avoid such contradictions. This has nothing to do with `sudo` and `NOPASSWD` though.

---

As additional candy, it might be nice if one can call your script directly without `sudo` and it elevates its privileges automatically if not already running as root. I've written a little Bash snippet for this once, it can simply be added to the top of any Bash script that needs to run as root:

```
#!/bin/bash
if test "$(id -u)" -ne 0 ; then
    sudo "$0" "$1"
    exit $?
fi
```

This tests if the effective user id is 0 (root) and if not, it executes its own script file with `sudo` and also passes its exit code through when terminating. This works well together with a `NOPASSWD` setting for the script file.